# Wrong numeric key when using php array_merge_recursive

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, merge

I am trying to recursively merge two arrays using array_replace_recursive.
This is the code:

```
$col = array();
$new = array_merge_recursive($col, array('table1' => array(1 => true)));
$new = array_merge_recursive($new, array('table1' => array(0 => false)));
```

The dump of the $new array is

```
array(1) { ["table1"]=> array(2) { [1]=> bool(true) [2]=> bool(false) } }
```

What i need is to preserve the numeric keys of the "table1" array. The expected result should be

```
array(1) { ["table1"]=> array(2) { [0]=> bool(false) [1]=> bool(true) } }
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Use `array_replace_recursive` instead of `array_merge_recursive`.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work. Please, submit an answer to confirm. @ThinkDifferent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_replace_recursive` instead of `array_merge_recursive`.

Answer (score 0):

You could switch the order of your arguments

```
$new = array_merge_recursive(array(), array('table1' => array(0 => false)));
$new = array_merge_recursive($new, array('table1' => array(1 => true)));
```

The problem you're running into is you already created a key so subsequent calls will append to the first element of the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works too, only that i am doing more than two merges with stored keys and it would imply sorting first, when array_replace_recursive does it without sorting